# Selectively Updating XML Child Element Values Based on Adjacent Child Element Values

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have an .XML file that looks like the following:

```
<Compliance_Items>
  <Compliance_Item>
    <Application_Name>Notepad++</Application_Name>
    <Installed_Version>6.5.3</Installed_Version>
    <Required_Version>6.5.4</Required_Version>
    <Detected_Missing_Date-UTC>2/27/2014 7:53:17 AM</Detected_Missing_Date-UTC>
    <Detected_Missing_Date-LocalTime>2/26/2014 11:53:17 PM</Detected_Missing_Date-    LocalTime>
    <Used_Deferrals>1</Used_Deferrals>
  </Compliance_Item>
  <Compliance_Item>
    <Application_Name>VLC media player 2.1.3</Application_Name>
    <Installed_Version>2.1.3</Installed_Version>
    <Required_Version>2.1.4</Required_Version>
    <Detected_Missing_Date-UTC>2/27/2014 7:53:18 AM</Detected_Missing_Date-UTC>
    <Detected_Missing_Date-LocalTime>2/26/2014 11:53:18 PM</Detected_Missing_Date-    LocalTime>
    <Used_Deferrals>1</Used_Deferrals>
  </Compliance_Item>
</Compliance_Items>
```

I'm iterating through a list of application names and presenting users with an "Upgrade or Defer" prompt. If they defer, I increment a counter. That counter needs to be written back to the .XML (i.e. `<Used_Deferrals>1</Used_Deferrals>` should become `<Used_Deferrals>2</Used_Deferrals>`.

I could foreach through each  child element group and look for where element.name matches the name of the application I'm currently processing, but from there I don't know how to select the adjacent  child element so that I can update its value.

Comment: Why not deserialize the XML into corresponding Class files? Modify the instance and write the serialized stream as XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `XDocument` LINQ to XML class:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(...);
var elementToUpdate = xDoc.Root
                          .Descendants("Compliance_Item")
                          .Single(ci => ci.Element("Application_Name").Value == "Notepad++")
                          .Element("Used_Deferrals");
elementToUpdate.Value = (Int32.Parse(elementToUpdate.Value) + 1).ToString();
```

However, if you're planning some more complicated manipulations of the structure, it really might be useful to follow @Abhinav's advice and deserialize the XML prior to processing.